# Where can I find a good interactive polyhedron animation tool?

Tags: group-theory, education, polyhedra, visualization, online-resources

I'm planning to talk about symmetry groups of regular polyhedra in a class.  I'd like to find a decent computer animation of polyhedra, which would ideally not just allow me to spin a picture of one around, but also make it easy to visualize the axis of rotation of symmetries, and/or to mark certain subsets of a regular polyhedron (e.g., for explaining how the symmetry group of the icosahedron is a subgroup of $S_5$).

Does anyone know any good resources?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question over at the mathematics educators SE: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had no idea there was such a place

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to do in Maple, once you learn how to use it.  For example:

```
with(geom3d):
TruncatedIcosahedron(t, point(o,0,0,0),1):
draw(t, viewpoint="circleleft",lightmodel=light3);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or *Mathematica*:

```
PolyhedronData["GyroelongatedPentagonalBicupola"]
```

[image]

and related figures:

```
PolyhedronData["GyroelongatedPentagonalBicupola", "NetImage"]
```

[image]